# basic install of nginx, connection refused

Tags: nginx

I created a new virtual enviroment and ran

```
sudo apt-get install nginx
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx start
```

Next I try to reach the basic “Welcome to nginx!” page using `curl -v 0.0.0.0:80` in a second terminal but it returns an error:

```
$ curl 0.0.0.0:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 80: Connection refused
(data_collection_project_retry)rootadmin@annotatie01:/data_nfs/data_
```

No error is outputed to the terminal. What is wrong? Why isn't it working?

Comment: As you are running a virtual environment you need to make sure your ports are forwarded properly. In OSX you usually can't forward any ports below 1024 successfully and therefore need to use 8080. Are you using docker or a full-fledged VM solution like VMWare? Or are you referencing python's virtualenv?

Comment: It's an ubuntu 12.04 server. It's a physical box somewhere, but I only have SSH access.

Comment: Have you verified that it's up using `netstat -tuplen | grep ":80"` or similar? Also do the iptables look fine?

Comment: It is listening on the port (8433) according to `netstat`. How can i check the iptables?

Comment: `sudo iptables -L`

Comment: Can you successfully connect to it on port 8433? Alternatively 127.0.0.1:8433

Comment: iptables returns 
`Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination`

Comment: Can't connect to ip:8443 or 127.0.0.1:8433

Comment: I do think default nginx configuration only bind to localhost. Try `curl http://localhost -v`